# Get objects of a certain quality from many to many field

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many

Say I have the following model:

```
class Project(Model):
    name = CharField()
    users = ManyToManyField(), through="Membership")

    @property
    def developers(self):
        ???


class Membership(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    project = ForeignKey(Group)
    level = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "project")
```

Say there are two levels: developer and tester. Which code shall be written instead of `???` so that `project.developers` returns a queryset of all users related to the project as developers?

Comment: How  you identify developers or testers in your DB ??

Comment: Integer 1 for tester and 2 for developer, but imagine a charfiled with choices if it is more suitable for you.